# LINQ to SQL Wildcards

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, wildcard

How can I build in wildcards to my LINQ To SQL lambda expression?

This is what I have currently:

```
var query = from log in context.Logs select log;
foreach (string filter in CustomReport.ExtColsToFilter)
{
    string tempFilter = filter;
    query = query.Where(Log => Log.FormattedMessage.Contains(tempFilter));
}
```

This works fine up until I try and pass wildcards in the filter string. I'm experimenting with `SqlMethods.Like()` but to no avail.

The filters above look like this: `"<key>NID</key><value>mcass</value>"`.

I'd like to be able to pass filters like this: `"<key>NID</key><value>%m%</value>"`

Comment: `SqlMethods.Like` should work. What is the result when you try it?

Comment: @Thorarin The resulting SQL is the same as the .Contains() SQL. Maybe I need to focus more on embedding wildcards?

Comment: just to be clear, are you passing in `"<key>NID</key><value>%m%</value>"` to `SqlMethods.Like` and still getting the same result as you were without the `%` wildcards?

Comment: @Ahmad Actually, no. When I pass the string you mention to the SqlMethods.Like() method, the SQL output is this: 
WHERE ([t0].[FormattedMessage] LIKE @p0 ESCAPE '~')
...interesting...

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on in your specific case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String.Contains` is actually implemented as a `LIKE` expression in LINQ to SQL, so these queries would be equivalent:

```
query = query.Where(Log => Log.FormattedMessage.Contains("m"));
query = query.Where(Log => SqlMethods.Like(Log.FormattedMessage, "%m%"));
```

However, with `SqlMethods.Like`, you can specify more complex patterns, such as `"%m%a%"`. Works fine for me. You can't really see the difference from inside visual studio, because the expression to be matched against is put inside a parameter in the T-SQL.

If you were to log the SQL query in a profiler, it would look something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[FormattedMessage]
FROM [dbo].[Log] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[FormattedMessage] LIKE @p0',N'@p0 nvarchar(5)',@p0=N'%m%a%'
```

Not relevant to the question per se, but `String.StartsWith` and `String.EndsWidth` also translate to a SQL `LIKE`, with slightly different patterns of course.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm beginning to think that my problem lies with the filters themselves. If you look at the bottom of my question, I give to strings that I am querying for. The first returns a record. The second, doesn't. If it helps, I'm querying a SQL column that contains xml similar to my filter examples.

Comment: @mcass20: That's very odd. If the first filter returns a record, the second filter should definitely return at *least* one. If you have SQL Profiler, it might be of help to figure out what's going on.

Comment: If you don't have SQL Profiler, attaching `Console.Out` (or another TextWriter) to `context.Log` would also work, of course.

Comment: The SQL output looks as it should and I've narrowed it down to the string itself. "%m%" returns records, but "<key>NID</key><value>%m%</value>" does not. As you suggested, I also tried "%<key>NID</key><value>%m%</value>%"...no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard is such as, m*, so anything with an m, for the wildcard you can ask if it .Contains(m); and it will get anything containing 'm'.

If you need wildcard in the sense of ALL the results from that table, just use

```
query.ToList();
```

You now have the entire list of Logs.

Hope that helps.

Comment: if you need to get multiple strings, you can use the ForEach statement, and check on each string and tack it on to a local list with each string.

"List<string> Rules = new List<string>();
var Logs = new List<Log>();
Rules.ForEach(rule => Logs.Add(query.Contains(rule)));"

I believe that should work!