# Linq to SQL, is there support for a mid-string % wildcard?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Selecting from Linq to Sql, I want to have a string search using wildcards. So far I understand it is possible to do the following

```
%token = column.EndsWith(value)
token% = column.StartsWith(value)
%token% = column.Contains(value)
```

What I can't seem to find support for is

```
to%ken
```

Is that supported in any way?

Update - people have suggested SqlMethods.Like - however this doesn't seem to work in the usage I have, code below

```
if (!object.Children.Any() || 
    !object.Children.OrderByDescending(t => t.Version)
        .First().MetaDataPairs.Any(mdp => SqlMethods.Like(mdp.Value.ToLower(), stringmatch))) continue;
```

and error I get when trying this

> Error was Method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' cannot
>   be used on the client; it is only for translation to SQL.

Comment: See the not accepted but more upvoted answer from Ryan here, is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040380/wildcard-search-for-linq

Comment: Check also this one out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000153/linq-to-sql-wildcards

Comment: @Equalsk This is specific for Linq to Sql.

Comment: @J.Pichardo Err, isn't that exactly what OP wants? It's in the title of the post and the first 5 words of the post. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Equalsk You're right.

Comment: Since this question is locked because it is duplicate I cannot answer here. But I've posted an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040380/wildcard-search-for-linq/42307642#42307642

Answer (score 1):

In the namespace `SqlMethods` there is a `like` method, you could use it like:

```
Where SqlMethods.Like(entity.StringProperty, "tok%en");
```

This only works for Linq to Sql queries, if you want a more general approach I would recommend using Regex, something like:

```
.Where(entity => Regex.matches(entity.StringProperty, @"(?:tok)(\w*)(?:en)");
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the other Linq syntax, eg I need it in the below structure but it doesn't seem to work in this usage. (mentioned above)

Comment: Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

2 suggestions:

1) Using

```
SqlMethods.Like
```

2) Using Regex like

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regEx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("token");
```

Comment: Regex is better in case the ORM is changed from LINQ to SQL to EF or NHibernate for instance.